# Why Can't read full json data from internet or local file(File size is medium big)

Tags: android, json

When I read the JSON file from local or internet, It's only a few of line can read. It should be returned the Whole json file but didn't return it. Plz, give me a solution.
Example:

Link of API: https://confutable-colon.000webhostapp.com/api.php

/* there have 200 more lines on the file but show only a few of lines*/

```
        String     json      =     null;
        InputStream     is    =   
        context.getAssets().open("info.json");

        int    size   =    is.available();
        byte[]    buffer    =    new    byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        json    =     new     String(buffer,  "UTF-8");

    Log.d("Full JSON",json);
    return json;
```

Comment: `Log.e()` will not show the full text, if that text is long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Logcat can display only upto 4000 characters after that it'll split.
To show your complete Log use a custom fuction to display log just like

```
public static void CompleteLog(String tag, String content) {
   if (content.length() > 4000) {
       Log.d(tag, content.substring(0, 4000));
       largeLog(tag, content.substring(4000));
   } else {
       Log.d(tag, content);
   }
}
```

Comment: But When I am trying to add my recycler view,it can't find all of my data.Not a problem on log but also in using data

Comment: How do you recieve data, via Internet or Local.?

Comment: Local JSON file or Api response JSON file

using AsyncTask

Comment: Are you using retrofit for API Parsing.?

Comment: No I am trying to :
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(populationJSON);

I don't know retrofit for API Parsing

Comment: It may happen because of too much data in MainThread. Why don't you try Retrofit for API parsing, I think It'll work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation.
I will try it.